# Thrust has no member device_malloc error when compiling gDel3D (3D Delaunay Triangulation with GPU)

Tags: linux, cmake, nvidia, thrust, delaunay

I tried several different methods of building this library and all have resulted in "thrust" has no member "device_malloc".

The following is a link to the git repo for gDel3D: [https://github.com/ashwin/gDel3D][1]

The following is the error I receive when typing: make

```
make
[ 7%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/gflip3d_generated_ThrustWrapper.cu.o
/home/gDel3D/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/ThrustWrapper.cu(121): error: namespace "thrust" has no member "device_malloc"

/home/gDel3D/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/ThrustWrapper.cu(121): error: type name is not allowed

/home/gDel3D/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/ThrustWrapper.cu(121): error: expression must have class type

/home/gDel3D/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/GPUDecl.h(280): error: namespace "thrust" has no member "device_malloc"

/home/gDel3D/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/GPUDecl.h(280): error: type name is not allowed

5 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00000a74_00000000-7_ThrustWrapper.compute_30.cpp1.ii".
CMake Error at gflip3d_generated_ThrustWrapper.cu.o.Release.cmake:279 (message):
Error generating file
/home/gDel3D/build/CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/./gflip3d_generated_ThrustWrapper.cu.o

CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/gflip3d_generated_ThrustWrapper.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/gflip3d_generated_ThrustWrapper.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried asking my question on the issues tab of the gDel3D forum, but thought it may be appropriate here as it seems to be a problem with configuring the thrust library. Thanks for the help!

Edit:
I tried the first suggestion below and have received more errors. I also tried switching OS. I am now running on Ubuntu 18.04

```
The following is the new error
user@user-Oryx-Pro:~/Documents/gFlip3D-Release_271/build$ cmake ..
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Documents/gFlip3D-Release_271/build
user@user-Oryx-Pro:~/Documents/gFlip3D-Release_271/build$ make 
[  7%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/gflip3d_generated_GpuDelaunay.cu.o
/home/user/Documents/gFlip3D-Release_271/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GpuDelaunay.cu(839): error: namespace "thrust" has no member "gather"

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00002cd3_00000000-8_GpuDelaunay.compute_50.cpp1.ii".
CMake Error at gflip3d_generated_GpuDelaunay.cu.o.Release.cmake:279 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/Documents/gFlip3D-Release_271/build/CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/./gflip3d_generated_GpuDelaunay.cu.o


CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/build.make:924: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/gflip3d_generated_GpuDelaunay.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/gflip3d_generated_GpuDelaunay.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gflip3d.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

if it helps, i ran `cmake -LA .`

```
cmake -LA .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Documents/gFlip3D-Release_271/build
-- Cache values
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ar
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/c++
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ar-7
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-7
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/cc
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ar-7
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-7
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=OFF
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ld
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/make
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CMAKE_NM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/nm
CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/objcopy
CMAKE_OBJDUMP:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/objdump
CMAKE_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ranlib
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=NO
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CMAKE_STRIP:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/strip
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=FALSE
CUDA_64_BIT_DEVICE_CODE:BOOL=ON
CUDA_ATTACH_VS_BUILD_RULE_TO_CUDA_FILE:BOOL=ON
CUDA_BUILD_CUBIN:BOOL=OFF
CUDA_BUILD_EMULATION:BOOL=OFF
CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so
CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
CUDA_GENERATED_OUTPUT_DIR:PATH=
CUDA_HOST_COMPILATION_CPP:BOOL=ON
CUDA_HOST_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/cc
CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS:STRING=
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS:BOOL=ON
CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR:PATH=CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND
CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION:BOOL=OFF
CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE:PATH=/usr/local/cuda/include
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/cuda
CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME:BOOL=ON
CUDA_VERBOSE_BUILD:BOOL=OFF
CUDA_VERSION:STRING=10.0
CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so
CUDA_cublas_device_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=CUDA_cublas_device_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CUDA_cudadevrt_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a
CUDA_cudart_static_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a
CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so
CUDA_cupti_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64/libcupti.so
CUDA_curand_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcurand.so
CUDA_cusolver_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcusolver.so
CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcusparse.so
CUDA_nppc_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppc.so
CUDA_nppial_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppial.so
CUDA_nppicc_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppicc.so
CUDA_nppicom_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppicom.so
CUDA_nppidei_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppidei.so
CUDA_nppif_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppif.so
CUDA_nppig_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppig.so
CUDA_nppim_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppim.so
CUDA_nppist_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppist.so
CUDA_nppisu_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppisu.so
CUDA_nppitc_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnppitc.so
CUDA_npps_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnpps.so
CUDA_rt_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so
```

I tried the zip suggested by @Snowie and modifying CmakeLists.txt file

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS
    ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
    -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35
    -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30
    -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50)
```

Which also did not work.

Following Snowie's suggestion, I went ahead and added `#include <thrust/gather.h>` to GPUDelaunay. The build was successful but did not run.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem with GDel3D. A quick fix for this issue is to include necessary thrust files where needed. For device_malloc include <thrust/device_malloc.h>. Based on your error message it would seem you need to include it in gFlip3D-Release_271/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GpuDelaunay.cu.
I also had better luck with a version of GDel3D you can get from this website:

https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~tants/gdel3d.html

more specifically from here:

https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~tants/gdel3d_files/gDel3D-Release_271.zip

Also you may want to try out different versions of CUDA Toolkit. And additionally you can modify the CMakeLists.txt file at the lines with "-gencode arch=compute_##,code=sm_##". That should allow you to specify different CUDA compute capabilities and such. I'm pretty new to CUDA myself so I might be wrong here.

I managed to run the version of GDel3D I linked to without any errors. It compiled and ran on GeForce GT 840m and CUDA 7.5.17 on Linux Mint (not sure of the version though exactly). Also I added includes for missing thrust functions and modified the CMakeLists.txt with "arch=compute_50,code=sm_50".

Hope any of this helps.

edit1:

Your new error indicates the fix worked, you just need to add all the thrust header files that are needed.

You have to read the error messages:

/home/user/Documents/gFlip3D-Release_271/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GpuDelaunay.cu(839): error: namespace "thrust" has no member "gather"

this line tells you that you need to include header for gather function in gFlip3D-Release_271/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GpuDelaunay.cu

Try googling for the proper header where this function is declared/defined if similar error comes up again. This time "#include <thrust/gather.h>" in gFlip3D-Release_271/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GpuDelaunay.cu should fix the problem.

edit2:

Since you are using RTX 2070, you might want to try using this in your CMakelists.txt (make sure you are using CUDA Toolkit 10.0):

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS
    ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
    -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75)
```

or

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS
    ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
    -D_FORCE_INLINES
    -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75)
```

This should make CUDA Toolkit use the most recent compute capability. Also you can try changing the ## parts in "compute_##" and "sm_##".

According to what I found on wiki your GPU is only supported by CUDA Toolkit versions 10.0–10.2 and these versions of the toolkit apparently support following compute capabilities: 3.0–7.5. So make sure you try these versions of CUDA Toolkit and these compute capabilities.

Comment: Where do I include <thrust/device_malloc.h>?

Comment: Based on your error message it would seem you need to include it in gFlip3D-Release_271/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GpuDelaunay.cu. Going to add this to my answer.

Comment: @CodeGuyRoss include location was added to the answer.

Comment: Ive wiped the linux machine and started from scratch. This still doesnt work.

Comment: I dont think i follow what you mean in your answer. Please elaborate further @Snowie

Comment: @CodeGuyRoss I editted the main answer based on the new error. Also what GPU are you using in the system? After you get it to build you may still have trouble running it based on the compute capability of your GPU. For me using the highest compute capability available on my GPU usually fixed this problem on linux.

Comment: I went ahead and added "#include <thrust/gather.h>" to GPUDelaunay  and the build was successful. However the code is not running as it says my video card is not cuda capable. However, I have a NVIDIA RTX 2070

Comment: The problem now is that ubuntu is not recognizing my video card regardless of having the NVIDIA drivers installed, however I think this would work if the video card was recognized.

Comment: @CodeGuyRoss well even after building successfully I had trouble running the program myself so you may experience similar issues. I have added more info into the main answer that may help you if you have further troubles with running it after you get your drivers and CUDA Toolkit working properly.

Comment: I was able to come up with a full working example based on your comments so I went ahead and awarded you the bounty. Thanks again for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Before I go into the steps I took, I wanted to give a special thanks to @Snowie for their time and help in getting me to a solution.I started from a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04 with the following commands in the terminal. Some of these installs are not necessary but will save me time later.

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt-get install build essential
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libxi-dev libxmu-dev
sudo apt install curl
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo apt install cmake
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt install gcc-6 g++-6 gcc-7 g++-7 gcc-8 g++-8 gcc-9 g++-9
    
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 90 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-9
    
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 80 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-8
    
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 70 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-7
    
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-6
```

Now I can choose the version of gcc that I want to run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

> There are 4 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).
>
> ```
>   Selection    Path            Priority   Status
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> * 0            /usr/bin/gcc-9   90        auto mode
>   1            /usr/bin/gcc-6   60        manual mode
>   2            /usr/bin/gcc-7   70        manual mode
>   3            /usr/bin/gcc-8   80        manual mode
>   4            /usr/bin/gcc-9   90        manual mode
>
> Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
> ```

In this case I choose 1 to select gcc-6

Now its time to install the cuda-toolkit

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

You should see output from `nvcc --version` similiar to

```
nvcc --version
```

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017 Cuda compilation
> tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85

Now download 3dDelaunay from here: “[https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~tants/gdel3d_files/gDel3D-Release_271.zip](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/%7Etants/gdel3d_files/gDel3D-Release_271.zip)”

Inside /home/user/Documents/gFlip3D-Release_271/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GpuDelaunay.cu you need to add “`#include <thrust/gather.h>`”

Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
#include "GpuDelaunay.h"

#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>

#include "GPU/CudaWrapper.h"
#include "GPU/HostToKernel.h"
#include "GPU/KerCommon.h"
#include "GPU/KerPredicates.h"
#include "GPU/KerDivision.h"
#include "GPU/ThrustWrapper.h"
#include <thrust/gather.h>
```

Now you need to set your target compute architecture. My video card is a RTX 2070. Accord to nvidia my compute architecture and compute capability are 7.5. I tried these numbers and it did not work. I thought maybe since the cuda version I ended up with was not 10.2 and was instead 10.1, that I needed to target a little less on my architecture. I targetted 7.0 compute capability and compute architecture instead.

Here is an example in the CMakeLists.txt file.

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS
    ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
    -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70)
```

Now lets go ahead and create the build folder from the gFlip3D-Release_271 folder

```
mkdir build
cd build    
cmake ..
make
```

And last run `./gflip3d`

> ```
> Generating input... Constructing 3D Delaunay triangulation... Checking... V: 100001 E: 772552 F: 1345102 T: 672551 Euler: 0 Euler
> check:  Pass Orient check: Pass Adjacency check: Pass
>
> Convex hull facets: 412
>
> Delaunay check: Pass
>
> ---- SUMMARY ----
>
> PointNum       100000 FP Mode        Double
>
> TotalTime (ms)     101.19 InitTime       139861894.77 SplitTime       
> 5.20 FlipTime            68.93 RelocateTime         8.11 SortTime             1.05 OutTime              9.87 SplayingTime         3.65
>
> # Flips           1422073
> # Failed verts        109
> # Final stars         243
> ```

Edit* I have found a possibly easier way to fix this issue with device_malloc than what i have listed above. In order to correct the missing member device_malloc add a reference to the file in the two files where it is used.

The two files you need to modify with the new reference

```
/home/gFlip3D-Release_271/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/ThrustWrapper.cu
/home/gFlip3D-Release_271/GDelFlipping/src/gDel3D/GPU/GPUDecl.h
```

The magical line to add

```
#include <thrust/device_malloc.h>
```

I hope this helps others with their research leveraging the gDel3D!

Comment: Adding the include lines works for me!